# Alternator fuse keeps blowing, odometer keeps resetting and car won't start

Tags: electrical, starting, troubleshooting, hyundai, sonata

I have an 06 Hyundai Sonata and I had my alternator replaced by a neighbor.

Now my alternator fuse keeps blowing, my windows won't roll up, my car won't start, and the odometer reset to 0.

What could be wrong?